# Socket error (only when using it into a windows service)

Tags: c#, sockets, service

My problem is only happening when I try to use my socket connection under a windows service.
Basically I have a socket client which connect to a remote server.
When I use it in a client application I don't have any problem at all.
But when I try to use it under my windows service it doesn't work.

public abstract class SocketClient
{
    public static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(SocketClient));

```
private System.Net.Sockets.Socket fSocket;
private bool LocalsocketClientIsShutingDown;
private byte[] readbuf;
private byte[] sendbuf;
private string currentmessage = "";

public event EventHandler ConnectionDone;
public event EventHandler ConnectionFailed;
public event EventHandler MessageReceivingFailed;
public event EventHandler MessageSendingFailed;

public SocketClient()
{
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    readbuf = new byte[16384];
    this.ConnectionDone += new EventHandler(OnSocketConnectionDone);
    this.ConnectionFailed += new EventHandler(OnSocketConnectionFailed);
    this.MessageSendingFailed += new EventHandler(OnMessageSendingFailed);
    this.MessageReceivingFailed += new EventHandler(OnMessageReceivingFailed);
}

public bool isConnected()
{
    if (fSocket == null)
        return false;
    return fSocket.Connected;
}

protected abstract void OnSocketConnectionDone(object sender, EventArgs e);
protected abstract void OnSocketConnectionFailed(object sender, EventArgs e);
protected abstract void OnMessageSendingFailed(object sender, EventArgs e);
protected abstract void OnMessageReceivingFailed(object sender, EventArgs e);

protected void ConnectToServer(string ServerName, int Port)
{
    try
    {
        log.Debug("SocketClient.ConnectToServer():" + ServerName);
        if (this.fSocket == null || !this.fSocket.Connected)
        {
            this.fSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream
                , ProtocolType.Tcp);

            IPAddress[] ipadress;
            log.Debug("ConnectToServer()1");
            IPHostEntry he = Dns.GetHostEntry(ServerName); //Dns.Resolve(ServerName);
            log.Debug("ConnectToServer()2" + he.HostName);
            ipadress = he.AddressList;
            //he.AddressList = he.AddressList.ToList().Where(ip => ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork).ToArray();
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipadress[0], Port);
            if (ServerName=="localhost")
            {
                IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = /*Dns.Resolve*/Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()); //Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
                //dont take IPv6 IPs
                //ipHostInfo.AddressList = ipHostInfo.AddressList.ToList().Where(ip => ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork).ToArray();
                IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
                remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, Port);
            }
            log.Debug("ConnectToServer()3: start BeginConnect()");
            this.fSocket.BeginConnect(remoteEP, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback)
                , this.fSocket);
            Trace.WriteLine("Connecting to server");
        }
        else
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Already connected to a Server");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Error connecting to server" + ex.ToString());
        OnConnectionFailed();
    }
}

private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    string[] obj;
    try
    {
        log.Debug("end BeginConnect with ConnectCallback()");
        System.Net.Sockets.Socket socket = (System.Net.Sockets.Socket)asyncResult.AsyncState;
        this.fSocket = socket;
        socket.EndConnect(asyncResult);

        this.LocalsocketClientIsShutingDown = false;

        this.fSocket.BeginReceive(this.readbuf, 0, this.readbuf.Length, SocketFlags.None
              , new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), this.fSocket);

        OnConnectionDone();

    }
    catch (SocketException ex)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Connection Failed: " + ex.Message);
        OnConnectionFailed();
    }
}

private void OnConnectionDone()
{
    log.Debug("OnConnectionDone");
    if (ConnectionDone != null)
    {
        ConnectionDone(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
private void OnConnectionFailed()
{
    log.Debug("OnConnectionFailed");
    if (ConnectionFailed != null)
        ConnectionFailed(this, new EventArgs());
}

public void SendMessage(string message)
{
    log.Debug(">>> Sending Message: " + message);
    if (this.fSocket != null && this.fSocket.Connected)
    {
        log.Debug(">>> Sending Message: Begin send 1:" + message);
        //Turn string into byte for network transfer
        this.sendbuf = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
        log.Debug(">>> Sending Message: Begin send 2:" + message);

        this.fSocket.BeginSend(this.sendbuf, 0, this.sendbuf.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback)
            , this.fSocket);
    }
    else
    {
        log.Debug("Cant Send Message: " + message + " _ Not connected to socket");
        Trace.WriteLine("Not connected to Server");
    }
}

private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    try
    {
        //On récupere le socket sur lequel on a envoyé les données
        System.Net.Sockets.Socket socket = (System.Net.Sockets.Socket)asyncResult.AsyncState;
        //on met fin à l'envois de données
        int senda = socket.ReceiveBufferSize;
        int send = socket.EndSend(asyncResult);

        Trace.WriteLine(">>> Message Sent: " + send + " bytes");
        log.Debug(">>> Message Sent: " + send + " bytes");
    }
    catch (SocketException ex)
    {
        log.Debug("!!! Message NOT Sent: " + ex.Message);
        Trace.WriteLine("!!! Message NOT Sent: " + ex.Message);
        OnMessageSendingFailed();
    }
}
private void OnMessageSendingFailed()
{
    log.Debug("OnMessageSendingFailed");
    if (MessageSendingFailed != null)
        MessageSendingFailed(this, new EventArgs());
}

public void ReceiveMessage()
{
    try
    {
        log.Debug(">>> ReceiveMessage");
        if (this.fSocket != null && this.fSocket.Connected)
            this.fSocket.BeginReceive(this.readbuf, 0, this.readbuf.Length, SocketFlags.None
                , new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), this.fSocket);
        else
        {
            log.Debug("Not Connected to Server");

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        OnMessageReceivingFailed();
    }
}
private void OnMessageReceivingFailed()
{
    log.Debug("OnMessageReceivingFailed");
    if (MessageReceivingFailed != null)
        MessageReceivingFailed(this, new EventArgs());
}

private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    string[] obj;

    log.Debug("ReceiveCallback");
    try
    {
        System.Net.Sockets.Socket socket = (System.Net.Sockets.Socket)asyncResult.AsyncState;
        log.Debug("ReceiveCallback 2" + socket.ToString());

        int read = socket.EndReceive(asyncResult);

        if (read > 0)
        {
            currentmessage += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(this.readbuf, 0, read);
            log.Debug("ReceiveCallback 3" + currentmessage);
            char _charEOL = '\n';
            if (currentmessage[currentmessage.Length - 1] != _charEOL)
            {
                this.fSocket.BeginReceive(this.readbuf, 0, this.readbuf.Length, SocketFlags.None
                    , new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), this.fSocket);
                return;
            }
            readPacket(currentmessage.ToString());
            obj = new string[] { "\n\n Server says :" + currentmessage };
            currentmessage = "";
            Buffer.SetByte(this.readbuf, 0, 0);
            this.fSocket.BeginReceive(this.readbuf, 0, this.readbuf.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), this.fSocket);
        }
        if (read == 0 && !this.LocalsocketClientIsShutingDown)
        {
            this.fSocket.Close();
            obj = new string[] { "Close Remote Socket" };
            log.Debug("ReceiveCallback:Exception1-" + obj);
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException ex)
    {
        obj = new string[1] { ex.Message };
        log.Debug("ReceiveCallback:Exception2-" + ex.Message);
    }
}

public void readPacket(string aMessage)
{
    log.Debug("readPacket:"+aMessage);
    try
    {

        string _formattedMsg = aMessage.Replace("\n", "");
        string[] _tabAllMessages = _formattedMsg.Split(new char[] { '}' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        for (int i = 0; i <= _tabAllMessages.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            _tabAllMessages[i] = _tabAllMessages[i] + "}";
            //Trace.WriteLine("<<< Message Received: " + aMessage);
            readSingleMessage(_tabAllMessages[i]);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
    }
}

public abstract void readSingleMessage(string aMessage);//TO REDEFINE

public void Close()
{
    log.Debug("SocketClient:Close");
    try
    {
        if (this.fSocket != null && this.fSocket.Connected)
        {
            this.LocalsocketClientIsShutingDown = true;
            //On ferme le socket
            this.fSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

            //On détruit le socket
            this.fSocket.Close();

            Trace.WriteLine("Disconnected");
        }
    }
    finally
    {
    }
}
```

The problem seems to come from that line in ConnectCallBack():

this.fSocket.BeginReceive(this.readbuf, 0, this.readbuf.Length, SocketFlags.None
              , new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), this.fSocket);

I dont have any problem with that in a client application.
But when I use the socket in a windows service, it seems that if I keep that line, I will get a socket error a bit later.
If I dont keep the line, then both client and windows service wont be able to listen for some messages to read.

I m a bit lost as I used my windows application for a few month and never had an issue before I tried to turn it into a windows service.

Thanks!

EDIT: a few logs:

```
DEBUG2014-10-02 00:01:27 – Start Session
DEBUG2014-10-02 00:01:27 – Windows Service: Start Login
DEBUG2014-10-02 00:01:27 – ImgSocketClient:ConnectToServerAndSendPassword():xxxxxxxxx.com_23459
DEBUG2014-10-02 00:01:27 – SocketClient.ConnectToServer():xxxxxxxxx.com
DEBUG2014-10-02 00:01:27 – ConnectToServer()3: start BeginConnect()
DEBUG2014-10-02 00:01:27 – end BeginConnect with ConnectCallback()
DEBUG2014-10-02 00:01:27 – OnConnectionDone
DEBUG2014-10-02 00:01:28 – >>> Socket Connected - Sending Password
DEBUG2014-10-02 00:01:29 – >>> Sending Message: PASSWORD:xxx
DEBUG2014-10-02 00:01:29 – >>> Message Sent: 25 bytes
DEBUG2014-10-02 00:01:29 – ReceiveCallback
DEBUG2014-10-02 00:01:29 – **ReceiveCallback:Exception1-System.String[]**
DEBUG2014-10-02 00:01:29 – >>> Password Sent
DEBUG2014-10-02 00:01:29 – >>> Send Message to suscribe to updates
DEBUG2014-10-02 00:01:29 – >>> Sending Message: REQUEST:aaaaa
DEBUG2014-10-02 00:01:29 – Cant Send Message: REQUEST:aaaaa_ Not connected to socket
```

Comment: Is a SocketException trown? In that case, please share with us the SocketException.ErrorCode property.

Comment: Maybe it is a matter of rights. Click Windows `Start` and in the `Start programs...` text field enter `services.msc`. Services view opens. Locate your service, right-click on it and select `properties`. On the `Log on` tab, try to specify your own account instead of local service. What does it do (after restarting the service of course)? Does it still throw the error?

Comment: The exact problem under a windows service only is that at one point I receive a 0 byte in my ReceiveCallback(). So as per my code it stop the connection. But under a client application I never receive 0 byte.

Comment: I have already tried to use my account for the service but same problem.

Comment: When I launch my developped service by the code below, it s all fine. But when It s really laucnhed as a real service it doesnt work :(

System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
                        ServicesToRun = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase[] { new WindowsService() };
                        System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);

Comment: Could it be that Windows firewall is blocking the access to the port from your service? In the past I have found out that I had to add a rule to the firewall to allow the application (in your case: your service) access AND you have to open the port. Most probably the latter is already the case because your client application worked.

Comment: I have already tried to stop the firewall but no result :(
Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in lines:

```
if (read == 0 && !this.LocalsocketClientIsShutingDown)
        {
            this.fSocket.Close();
            obj = new string[] { "Close Remote Socket" };
            log.Debug("ReceiveCallback:Exception1-" + obj);
        }
```

It is normal if You receive 0 bytes. Why did you close the socket in this case? After closing the socket you can't send the message "REQUEST:aaaaa"...

Remove these lines and try again.

Comment: It s the same.I end with a Socket error.
System.Net.Sockets Error: 0 : [1360] Socket#63062333::UpdateStatusAfterSocketError() - ConnectionAborted
System.Net.Sockets Error: 0 : [1360] Exception dans Socket#63062333::BeginSend - Une connexion établie a été abandonnée par un logiciel de votre ordinateur hôte.
As I said in the comments, the problem is that I m receving 0 byte which never happens when I m using the socket under my client application.

Comment: Can you capture network dump by Wireshark, for example and determine which side aborts connection? If the FIN or RST packet arrives from server, you should look at the server, why it aborts connection. Also, it is useful to compare the two network dumps - when the request has been successfully processed and when you get an error.